# How to create a Multipart request using WLResourceRequest in Android

Tags: java, android, multipartform-data, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I've created a Java adapter which accepts Multipart Form data. Now I want to create a multipart request from my native Android App. But I'm not able to figure out how to construct a multipart request using WLResourceRequest class in MobileFirst API. Any example or pointer in this direction will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needn't do this via WLResourceRequest in the client-side.

IMO what you should do is something similar to this:

```
// Create the request to send
final HttpPost post = new HttpPost("your-destination");

// Construct the body of the object...
...
...

// Send the request and get the response
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

If you have security involved, you may want to read the following documentation as well (think POST instead of GET): http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_custom_request_to_resource_java.html?lang=en

Comment: Thanks it works now! But for some strange reason the authentication API's use Apache HttpClient which is deprecated in Android. So I had to write those API's and their logic (Using decompiled WLAuthorizationManager class) using URLConnection of Android. But thanks for the pointer towards how to handle security.

Comment: Deprecated does not mean removed, just yet. We are aware of the changes in Android and will work on addressing them.